A simple model in OpenModelica (RC circuit defined by the connexions between its components, not equations)
I am trying to test this simple circuit in OMEdit and OMShell, but it fails. Why?
model RCCircuit
  // Components
  Resistor R1(R=1e3); // Resistor with value 1k ohms
  Capacitor C1(C=1e-6); // Capacitor with value 1uF
  Voltage V1(V=10); // Voltage source with value 10V
  
  // Connections
  equation
    connect(V1.p, R1.p); // Connect positive terminal of the voltage source to resistor
    connect(R1.n, C1.p);  // Connect resistor to the capacitor
    connect(C1.n, V1.n);  // Connect the negative terminal of the capacitor to the negative terminal of the voltage source

end RCCircuit;


I've got the following (good) answer by Perplexity AI :
model RCCircuit
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor R1(R=100);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Capacitor C1(C=1e-3);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage V1(V=5);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground;
equation
  connect(V1.p, R1.p);
  connect(R1.n, C1.p);
  connect(C1.n, V1.n);
  connect(V1.n, ground.p);
end RCCircuit;


This solution is working fine.
Both corrections are :

The definition of the components
Addition of the ground without which the following error occurs: "Internal error Circular Equalities Detected for Variables"

I am very surprised that an AI. Hurrah for progres

Now, I'll aim to know how add init conditions for Capacitor voltage and Inductior current?

Once again, Perplexity gave me the right answer :
model RCCircuit
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Resistor R1(R=100);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Capacitor C1(C=1e-3);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.ConstantVoltage DCSource(V=5);
  Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Basic.Ground ground;

initial equation
  C1.v = 2; // Set initial voltage of the capacitor to 2V

equation
  connect(DCSource.p, R1.p);
  connect(R1.n, C1.p);
  connect(C1.n, DCSource.n);
  connect(DCSource.n, ground.p);
end RCCircuit;
```

I will unsubscribe from Stackoverflow ;)

Here are the elecrical diagram and the step response curves:



For info:
model RC_Circuit_with_Equations
parameter Real R = 1e2; // Resistance in ohms (100Ω)
parameter Real C = 1e-3; // Capacitance in farads (1µF)
parameter Real V0 = 10; // Initial voltage of the voltage source (10V)
// Variables
Real vC(start = 0); // Voltage across the capacitor
Real i(start = 0); // Current in the circuit
// Equation for the current through the resistor and capacitor
equation
// Kirchhoff's voltage law
R * i + vC = V0;
// Current in the circuit
    i = C * der(vC);

end RC_Circuit_with_Equations;
